# Convert HTML Button into Laravel Collective Form::submit() with requirements

Tags: php, html, laravel-5.5, laravelcollective

Simply what will be the syntax or procedure to convert this :

```
<button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-save"></i><span> &nbsp; SAVE</span></button>
```

Into :

```
{{ Form::submit('SAVE', ['class' => 'btn btn-block btn-success btn-sm']) }}
```

Now how can I add a icon just before the text: SAVE and additional info.

Specifically : `<i class="fa fa-save"></i>`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 3):

Use like this

```
{{ Form::button('<i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i>', ['class' => 'btn btn-block btn-success btn-sm', 'type' => 'submit']) }}
```

Comment: now how to include a link with this button ?

Comment: {!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=> xyz\AddController@store', 'id'=> 'form']) !!}

<div class="form-group col-sm-5">
                {!! Form::label('student_id', 'Students:') !!}
                {!! Form::select('student_id', [''=>'Choose Options'] + $students , null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'student', 'name'=>'student_id'])!!}
            </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}                         How can i convert normal html form?